# How can I display a list of WordPress custom posts?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using WordPress 3, and I created a custom post type called article, which gives me the URL format of mywebsite/articles/article-title. How do I see all the article entries in the URL mywebsite/articles?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you set up everything correctly and you want to see the post type on a public template page, try this code into mycustomtemplate.php or the equivalent.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'article', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can customize the loop just like you would blog posts and pages. If you want to get *all* on one page you'll want to remove the limit of 10 on `post_per_page` I wouldn't suggest it though. I would say set it to 50 or 100 and still use pages.

Source: *[Custom post types in WordPress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress)*

Comment: How do i make mywebsite/articles use the template mycustomtemplate.php?

Comment: You should be able to add `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articles', 'with_front' => false ),` to your array when you set up the `register_post_type` variable. See the link I posted as the source above.

Comment: You should also be able to add something like single-mycustomtemplate.php

Answer (score 15):

I have the simplest solution. Just create file `archive-{custom post type}.php` and then, just do loop content as usual.

If you already set the permalink, just type `yourdomain.com/{custom post type}`.

Comment: This works great.  However, I've found that after creating a new custom post type, I have to go into Settings > Permalinks and click Save, which somehow refreshes the cache of permalinks.  Otherwise `yourdomain.com/{custom post type}` gives a 404 error.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I'm still getting the 404 even after following Simons instructions. I have the custom post type registered with `has_archive` set to true.

Comment: `If you already set the permalink` how does one do that? I'm seeing 404 too and don't know how to create a page for displaying **list** of posts from my custom post type

Comment: Ejay you can go into Settings > Permalinks and click Save, just like Simon say.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this from the definition of your custom post type, starting with WP 3.1. Just set `has_archive` to `true`.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_with_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types